# Difference between %something and %{$something}?

Tags: perl, syntax

Two (almost?) similar questions actually.

1. What is the difference between `%something` and `%{$something}` ?
2. What is the difference between `%{$hashvar{xyz}}` and `%hashvar{xyz}` ?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: also http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 4):

1. `%something` means `something` is a hash variable, and `%{$something}` means that `$something` is a scalar variable that contains a reference to a hash
2. `%{$hashvar{xyz}}` means `$hashvar{xyz}` (value associated with key `xyz` in hash `hashvar`) is a hash reference
3. Starting in Perl 5.20, `%hashvar{xyz}` is a [key/value hash slice](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.19.11/pod/perldata.pod#Key/Value_Hash_Slices), will return `'xyz'` and `$hashvar{xyz}`; before that, it is a syntax error.

---

References:
[perldata - Perl data types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)
[perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for your improvement.

Comment: In Perl 5.19.4 and above, `%hashvar{xyz}` is no longer a syntax error. It's a [key/value hash slice](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.19.11/pod/perldata.pod#Key/Value_Hash_Slices).